# What is the right type of contractor to fix slightly damaged house siding corner

Tags: exterior, siding

Sorry if I'm using incorrect terminology.

A car slightly damaged a corner of the house siding and I'm not sure what type of contractor should take a look into that. I need to make sure that it's properly fixed and sealed so that the moisture doesn't build up inside in the future.

[image: Here's what it looks like:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you could fix yourself using a pair of sheet metal seaming pliers.

These pliers have wide jaws and are basically a hand-held sheet metal brake. Using them should allow you to repair the damage. To do the repair, start with the most damaged part and slowly bend the metal back into shape.

You could then find some touch up paint that matches your siding as close as possible and paint over the spots where the paint chipped off.

I wouldn't be too concerned about moisture building up under the siding. That corner seam was never perfectly water tight to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the pliers recommendation. They were really helpful. I also bought an exterior sealing that happened to perfectly match the siding color, so it worked out pretty well and didn't cost much.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like few new materials will be needed, so I would search for a recommended handyman in your area.

You could also call a siding and roofing contractor, but I would expect this to be much more expensive than a handyman.  If siding needed replacement, this would probably be less hassle.